# What happens when the receiver of a parabolic antenna is covered by a metallic layer?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

[image]Out of curiosity I decided to conduct a small experiment and covered the receiver of the parabolic TV antenna with a metallic cylindrical food container without touching the receiver. It blocked the signals.

Now I am getting confused in explaining what exactly happened?

Elaboration:

The visible light gets scattered when obstructed by an opaque layer with non-uniformities on the surface. However talking about EM waves being blocked by a metal is getting me confused. To simply put my point, I am assuming just a time varying electric field as given in the image below.

A: an infinite sheet with time varying surface charge density that can generate a signal

B: a metal block introduced to the electric field that is uniform at any instant

C: receiver

The electric field will be zero inside the metal block but will not be affected anywhere else. Hence the receiver should not have any problem getting the signal.

But that is not what happened. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Would you also be confused if you placed a bucket over your head and could no longer see? It's the same thing.

Comment: Yes. What happens to the EM waves? I know they no longer reach the point the way they did before. But how? How does a metallic layer block the EM waves? How can I explain that in terms of Physics?

Comment: It's called "reflection". The case that you are showing is only valid for DC fields. For AC fields you have to calculate Maxwell's equations inside a conducting material, which will give you a quantity called "skin-depth". Fields inside a conductor are attenuated exponentially due to this skin-depth and thus the waves do not continue "on the other side". Instead the incident energy gets reflected back into space.

Comment: @CuriousOne did you perhaps intend to post that as an answer?

Comment: @Asher: You are right. It is an (albeit short) answer, isn't it? Honestly, though, I like your bucket much better than my own answer. It's both true and funny... what else does one want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What actually happens is that electromagnetic waves are being reflected on the surface of the metal. The case that you are showing is only valid for DC fields. For AC fields you have to calculate Maxwell's equations inside a conducting material, which will give you skin-effect, which is characterized by a frequency dependent quantity called "skin-depth". Fields inside a conductor are attenuated exponentially due to this skin-depth and thus the waves do not continue "on the other side". Instead the incident energy gets reflected back into space, which means that the receiver is being shielded for wavelengths that are much smaller than the size of the metal object in front of it. For objects roughly the size of the wavelength we have to calculate or measure the reflections and the resulting scattering and diffraction explicitly, which can be quite difficult.

Comment: I got your explanation. However I want to know what will happen if I conduct the same experiment with the electric field of the given figure (the DC field as you called it) instead of the satellite EM radio waves.

Comment: In that case the metal simply acts as a conductor and you get a slightly reduced effective distance between the receiver and the charge surface that is the source of the field, i.e. the effective capacitance of the coupling is slightly increased, just the way you drew it. You wouldn't even need a solid block, you could have a thin foil on both sides facing the charged surfaces and the receiver and a thin wire connecting the two and it would still work to "transmit" the signal. That's how wires work for low frequencies, in general.